# Prove that exist a matrix $X \in \mathbb C^{m,n}$ for which $B=AX$

Tags: linear-algebra

> There are a matrices $A \in \mathbb C^{m,m}$ and $B \in \mathbb C^{m,n}$ for which $rank[A | B]=rank A$. Prove that exist a matrix $X \in \mathbb C^{m,n}$ for which $B=AX$.

I know that probably this task is really easy because the thesis seems quite obvious. However I really try to do it for a long time and I still can not prove it.

Can you get some tips?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Christoph If I have $rank[A | B]=rank A$ then I know that where I have the zero rows of matrix $A$ there are also zeroes of the matrix $B$ and I think that vectors in lines of matrix $A$ and $B$ are linearly dependent, so I have $B=AX$ but this proof it's not good and I do not know how to prove it in a better way.

Comment: You claim "so I have $B=AX$" without any justification, so this is not a proof at all. See my answer for an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The rank of a matrix $M\in K^{m\times n}$ with columns $M_1,\dots,M_n\in K^m$ is the dimension of $\langle M_1,\dots,M_n \rangle$ (the subspace of $K^m$ spanned by $M_1,\dots,M_n$). Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \operatorname{rank}(A|B)$ you have
$$
\langle A_1,\dots,A_m \rangle = \langle A_1,\dots,A_m,B_1,\dots,B_n\rangle.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: So columns $B$ are linearly dependent on $A$ but I don't know what I can do the next

Comment: Write each $B_i$ as a linear combination of the $A_i$. Try to combine all these equations into a matrix identity.

Comment: Ok - Do you mean that I should create linear transformation and find matrix of transformation? Ok, that works bot I am not sure if I can do just like that

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean exactly what I said. There are real number $x_{ij}$ such that $B_i = \sum_{j=1}^m x_{ji} A_j$. Letting $X=(x_{ij})$ yields $B = AX$.

Comment: Okay, I mean about something similar - thanks for help!